# how to make UIViewController Title show up on titleView in UINavigationController?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I thought, and I may be wrong, without doing anything, the titleView of UINavigationController default to the title of the UIViewController.

Mine is not the case and I wonder why?

I set the title of the UIViewController in the story board to @"Nearby". I confirm that it's indeed the title in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    PO(self.title);
    PO(self.navigationController.title);
```

Produce

```
self.title: Nearby
self.navigationController.title: (null)
```

I think I can programatically force my way and set the titleView to a UILabel with my title but I am not sure that would be the right way to do it.

I wonder why self.navigationController.title is not automatically set to self.title? If so when should it be set and where?

By the way, I added this line:

```
self.navigationController.title=self.title;
```

That doesn't help.

Update: Changing the NavigationItem Title Works. But that's awkward. Also how do I change that programatically?

Comment: Did you set the UIViewController's title via its `title` property? And do you really mean the `titleView` property of the UINavigationController / UINavigationItem or just the `title` property?

Comment: I added code to confirm. I set that up at viewDidLoad.